# Show only selected row in table and other row will hide on same time use Javascript

Tags: javascript

It is a room type selection. Here I want to select room type on this selection I want to show only that row which I was selected from dropdown and other row should be hide at same time.

```
<select onChange="onSelect(this)" class="col-Room" name="ACRoom">
  <option value="optionAC" >AC-Room</option>
  <option value="optionNAC">Non AC-Room</option>
</select>
```

This is javascript code which I am using for selection. But it is not working properly. Only second option is working on select and first option is not working properly on selection.

Please help me out.

```
<script>     

function onSelect(thisselect) {
  var selected = thisselect.options[thisselect.selectedIndex].value;
  toggleRow(selected);
}

function toggleRow(id) {
  var row = document.getElementById(id);
  if (row.style.display == '') {
    row.style.display = 'none';
  }
  else {
    row.style.display = '';
  }
}

function showRow(id) {
  var row = document.getElementById(id);
  row.style.display = '';
}

function hideRow(id) {
  var row = document.getElementById(id);
  row.style.display = 'none';
}

function hideAll() {
  hideRow('optionAC');
  hideRow('optionNAC');
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should hide other rows while showing some particular rows. While selecting first option, you are not hiding nonac rows. Also I suggest you to use classs names instead of ID, since table can have multiple ac/non-ac rows. The below code could help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rooms</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="ac">
            <td>AC room</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="nonac">
            <td>Non Ac room</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ac">
            <td>AC room</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="nonac">
            <td>Non Ac room</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<select onChange="onSelect(this)">
    <option value="ac">AC</option>
    <option value="nonac">NON AC</option>
</select>

<script>
    var ac = document.getElementsByClassName("ac");
    var nonac = document.getElementsByClassName("nonac");

    function onSelect(thisselect) {
        var selected = thisselect.options[thisselect.selectedIndex].value;
        toggleRow(selected);

    }

    function toggleRow(id) {

        if (id == "ac") {
            showac();
        } else {
            shownonac();
        }

    }

    function showac() {

        for (var i = 0; i < nonac.length; i += 1) {
            nonac[i].style.display = 'none';
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < ac.length; i += 1) {
            ac[i].style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    function shownonac() {

        for (var i = 0; i < ac.length; i += 1) {
            ac[i].style.display = 'none';
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < nonac.length; i += 1) {
            nonac[i].style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanq So much But I want to understand function showac () and shownonac() using for loop,how it is  working please describe it..

Comment: When you select Ac/Non-Ac in select option, we pass the value to toggleRow function via onSelect(), there we decide whether to show ac rooms or non-ac rooms. In a table you will have two or more ac/non-ac rooms. So while selecting ac, you have to hide all non-ac rows. In `<tr>` I use classname to differentiate, you can see I use variables to get those rows. In both functions showac() and shownonac() I iterate each row upto last row to decide whether to show or hide. For eg, take showac(), first I iterate over all nonac rows to hide it and then show all ac rows. for shownonac() I do viceversa.